# Is there a hook that I can use to detect if one of my hard drive partitions on my server is full?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partition, hook

I have a server with a partition that contains all the uploaded files from my users... It gets empty after the files received are send to the CDN.

Everything works. But I am worried that one day the partition might get full.

My first question is:

What happens when a Linux (Ubuntu 12) hard drive partition is full?

Is there a way that if my hard drive as certain amount of space on it, a script is executed? Maybe a Hook? So that I can stop my users from uploading for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Which, if any, system monitoring tools do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [simple thresholding tool like Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) would provide quick drop-in alerting for system resources.

It's well-supported, stable and is covered [heavily here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/monit).

The [examples](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples) in the documentation would work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: What about zabbix?

Comment: Zabbix is fine. I recommended Monit because it's lightweight and can install in a few minutes. Zabbix, ZenOSS, OpenNMS, etc. are all more involved.